# Avoid changing the address while send GET request (django)

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, django, django-forms

I have url `http://127.0.0.1:8000/profile/question/1/` and on the address i have form

i want to have like or dislike button on post. everything work fine but url change is the problem.

it's my code- >

```
    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object=self.get_object()
        context = super(QuestionDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        if "like" or "dislike" in self.request.GET:

            if "like" in self.request.GET:
                if bool(Like.objects.filter(user=self.request.user, question=self.get_object())) == True:
                    pass
                else:
                    Like.objects.create(user=self.request.user, question=self.get_object())

            elif "dislike" in self.request.GET:
                if bool(DisLike.objects.create(user=self.request.user, question=self.get_object())) == True:
                    pass
                else:
                    DisLike.objects.create(user=self.request.user, question=self.get_object())

        try:
            question = Question.objects.get(id=self.kwargs["pk"])
            context['detail'] = question
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            return reverse("Profile:error")
```

```
<form class="float-right block">
   <button type="submit"  name="like" class="block mb-2"></button>
   <button type="submit"  name="dislike" class="block"></button>
</form>
```

when i click for example like button, url changed and it's `http://127.0.0.1:8000/profile/question/1/?like=`
how to avoid this problem? and what is the problem?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is correct. When you have multiple submit buttons, on your backend you should have a way to know which submit button was selected. You should have a name and values for each button separately. For example:

```html
<form class="float-right block">
   <button type="submit" name="type" value="like" class="block mb-2"></button>
   <button type="submit" name="type" value="dislike" class="block"></button>
</form>
```

The `like` button will submit the form to:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/profile/question/1/?type=like
```

And `dislike` button will submit the form to:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/profile/question/1/?type=dislike
```

And then in your backend, you can get the type of that to submit button using:

```py
btype = request.GET.get('type', 'like')
# Or if the method of the form is POST use 
btype = request.POST.get('type', 'like')
```

Comment: So i can't avoid this problem?

Comment: @kokiwebaaa It is not changing the url. But, instead if you change the method of this form to `POST`, you won't see that